# Compiling x264 in MinGW

Tags: ffmpeg, software, x264

I'm trying to do a minimal build of ffmpeg in MinGW including x264.  For some reason the x264 package depends on ffms2 which depends on ffmpeg which itself has a huge list of dependencies.  I will try installing x264 from git instead, but I'm wondering why pacman has this circular dependency loop.

```
$ pacman -Si mingw-w64-x86_64-x264-git
Repository      : mingw64
Name            : mingw-w64-x86_64-x264-git
Version         : r2991.1771b556-1
Description     : Library for encoding H264/AVC video streams (mingw-w64)
Architecture    : any
URL             : https://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html
Licenses        : custom
Groups          : None
Provides        : mingw-w64-x86_64-x264
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread  mingw-w64-x86_64-l-smash  mingw-w64-x86_64-ffms2
Optional Deps   : None
Conflicts With  : mingw-w64-x86_64-x264
Replaces        : mingw-w64-x86_64-x264
Download Size   : 810.45 KiB
Installed Size  : 6823.71 KiB
Packager        : Alexey Pavlov <alexpux@gmail.com>
Build Date      : Fri Jan 17 03:22:53 2020
Validated By    : MD5 Sum  SHA-256 Sum  Signature
```

```
$ pacman -Su mingw-w64-x86_64-x264-git
:: Starting core system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
warning: dependency cycle detected:
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-ffmpeg will be installed before its mingw-w64-x86_64-x264-git dependency
warning: dependency cycle detected:
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-harfbuzz will be installed before its mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype dependency
warning: dependency cycle detected:
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-libwebp will be installed before its mingw-w64-x86_64-libtiff dependency

Packages (100) mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2-2.0.12-8  mingw-w64-x86_64-aom-2.0.1-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-boost-1.75.0-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-c-ares-1.16.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo-1.17.4-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-celt-0.11.3-4  mingw-w64-x86_64-ceres-solver-2.0.0-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-cppunit-1.15.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-curl-7.74.0-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-dav1d-0.7.1-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-eigen3-3.3.9-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-ffmpeg-4.3.1-7  mingw-w64-x86_64-ffms2-2.23.1-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-fontconfig-2.13.93-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-freeimage-3.18.0-5
               mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype-2.10.4-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-frei0r-plugins-1.7.0-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-fribidi-1.0.10-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-gavl-1.4.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-gflags-2.2.2-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-giflib-5.2.1-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2-2.66.4-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-glog-0.4.0-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-glsl-optimizer-git-r66914.9a2852138d-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-gnutls-3.7.0-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-graphite2-1.3.14-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-gsm-1.0.19-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-harfbuzz-2.7.4-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-hdf5-1.12.0-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-hlsl2glsl-git-r848.957cd20-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-68.2-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-ilmbase-2.5.4-4
               mingw-w64-x86_64-intel-tbb-1~2020.2-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-jansson-2.13.1-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-jasper-2.0.22-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-jemalloc-5.2.1-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-jxrlib-1.1-3  mingw-w64-x86_64-lame-3.100-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-lcms2-2.11-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-leptonica-1.80.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libarchive-3.5.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libass-0.15.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libbluray-1.2.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libcaca-0.99.beta19-5
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libdatrie-0.2.12-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libdeflate-1.7-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libexif-0.6.22-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libidn2-2.3.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libjpeg-turbo-2.0.5-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libmetalink-0.1.3-3
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libmfx-1.25-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libmodplug-0.8.9.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libmysofa-1.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libogg-1.3.4-3
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libpng-1.6.37-3  mingw-w64-x86_64-libpsl-0.21.1-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libraw-0.20.2-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libssh2-1.9.0-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libthai-0.1.28-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-libtheora-1.1.1-4
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libtiff-4.2.0-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libunwind-11.0.0-5  mingw-w64-x86_64-libvorbis-1.3.7-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libvpx-1.9.0-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-libwebp-1.1.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.10-5  mingw-w64-x86_64-lz4-1.9.3-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-lzo2-2.10-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-metis-5.1.0-3
               mingw-w64-x86_64-nettle-3.7-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-nghttp2-1.41.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-ogre3d-1.12.6-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-openal-1.20.1-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-openblas-0.3.13-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-opencore-amr-0.1.5-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv-4.5.1-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-openexr-2.5.4-4
               mingw-w64-x86_64-openjpeg2-2.3.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-pango-1.48.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre-8.44-2  mingw-w64-x86_64-pixman-0.40.0-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-protobuf-3.12.4-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-pugixml-1.11.4-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-rtmpdump-git-r514.c5f04a5-3  mingw-w64-x86_64-speex-1.2.0-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-speexdsp-1.2.0-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-srt-1.4.2-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-suitesparse-5.8.1-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-szip-2.1.1-2
               mingw-w64-x86_64-tesseract-ocr-4.1.1-6  mingw-w64-x86_64-tinyxml-2.6.2-4
               mingw-w64-x86_64-vulkan-headers-1.2.158-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-vulkan-loader-1.2.158-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-wavpack-5.3.0-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-wineditline-2.205-3
               mingw-w64-x86_64-xvidcore-1.3.7-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-zziplib-0.13.71-1
               mingw-w64-x86_64-x264-git-r2991.1771b556-1

Total Download Size:    269.17 MiB
Total Installed Size:  1332.63 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 1):

The included x264 cli app may depend on libavformat and libswscale, which is where the ffmpeg dependency comes in.

The libx264 wrapper in libavcodec depends on x264.